# C# Write/Read XMLTV to Database

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I am working on EPG application. The objectives are simple: 1) read XMLTV from url, 2) deserialize xml to objects and save to db, 3) read objects from db and serialize again.

To do this I use Entity Framework, code-first approach, because I think it's fastest way - I need to copy whole xml document and then paste special 'Paste XML as Classes' and then I got almost complete class model.
For demonstration purpose I will use only two classes from XMLTV - class for root element 'tv' and class for one child of root element called 'channel' ([whole XMLTV](http://wiki.xmltv.org/index.php/XMLTVFormat) contains 44 elements).

So far, I got classes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("tv")]
public class Tvs
{
    public Tvs()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int TvID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("channel")]
    public Channels[] channels { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source-info-url")]
    public string sourceinfourl { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source-info-name")]
    public string sourceinfoname { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source-data-url")]
    public string sourcedataurl { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("generator-info-name")]
    public string generatorinfoname { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("generator-info-url")]
    public string generatorinfourl { get; set; }


}

[Serializable]
public class Channels
{
    public Channels()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ChannelID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string[] url { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TvID")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Tvs Tv { get; set; } // navigation property

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int TvID { get; set; }
}
```

...i got context also:

```
class TvContext : DbContext
{
    public TvContext() : base("EntityDataModel") // connection string in App.config
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Tvs> tvs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Channels> channels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String url = "http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/htv1.hr/weekly_htv1.hr_tvprofil.net.xml";
        String xml;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            xml = client.DownloadString(url);
            //Console.WriteLine(xml);
        }

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tvs));
        Tvs result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            result = (Tvs)serializer.Deserialize(reader); // RESULT CONTAINS WHOLE DOCUMENT - TV AND CHANNELS ARE INITIALIZED
        }

        using (var db = new TvContext())
        {
            db.tvs.Add(result);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new TvContext())
        {
            var query = from b in db.tvs  // IN DB AND THIS QUERY VARIABLE ONLY TVS ARE INITIALIZED; B.CHANNELS ARE NULL
                        select b;

            foreach (Tvs item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(XmlManipulation.GetXMLFromObject(item));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**PROBLEM:** So as u can see in main program, i successfully get XML doc from url and deserialize it into Tvs object (with associated channels initialized). If i open db to view data, there are tvs, but not channels saved. Please, can anybody tell me what I do wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried adding the channels with `db.channels.Add(result.channels);`?

Comment: Hi @Equalsk thanks for reply. It works. Channels are written into db. They are still not initialized in query variable when I call linq query. How to include channels in linq query? I added valid navigation property to Tvs class -  **public IList<Channels> channelsProperty { get; set; }** - and tried query like this **var query = db.tvs.Include("channelsProperty");**, but channels are null in query variable.

Comment: Is that your actual code? I would have assumed it should be something like `var query = from b in db.tvs.Include("channels") select b;` - See [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)